# Trouble saving event in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I can save the event in my database but it saves a different date.

When I click on a date it asks for the event name and saves it. The event is saved on the current date of the day not on the day that I choose/click.

Also the time it saves on the database depends on the current time of the computer.

I am using v2.1

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        editable: true,
        events:  "http://localhost/fullcalendar/events.php",
        selectable:true,

        select: function(start,end,title,date){
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            //var eventData;
            if(title){
                 var start = $.fullCalendar.moment().format();
                 var end = $.fullCalendar.moment().format();
                 $.ajax({
                        url:'http://localhost/fullcalendar/add_events.php',
                        data: 'title=' + title +'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
                        type:"POST",
                        success: function(json){
                            alert('Added Sucessfully');
                        }   

                 });



                 eventData = {
                        title:title,
                        start:start,
                        end:end,

                 };
                 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); //this makes the event stick on the calendar but not save on the database
            }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        eventLimit:true,        



    });


});

 </script>
 <style>

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 40px auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `select` function you have the following code:

```
var start = $.fullCalendar.moment().format();
var end = $.fullCalendar.moment().format();
```

This means that you are overriding the `start` and `end` parameters. As you are using it, `start` and `end` will have the current datetime and not the datetime that the user has selected.

If you remove these two lines, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format(YYYY/MM/DD);

var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format(YYYY/MM/DD);
```

Comment: Please don't answer with just code without any explanation. Explain how the code actually *solves* the question.